# Set NewMessageSignature with Powershell without using Word

Tags: powershell, outlook

So far, the only way I've found to change the default New Message Signature in Outlook is by instantiating Word:

```
$MSWord = New-Object -COMObject word.application 
$MSWord.EmailOptions.EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature="New Default"
$MSWord.Quit()
```

I don't fully understand what this snippet is doing, but it works.

The script is run at user Logon with a GPO, and results in Outlook's login prompt appearing for a few seconds while the value is being updated.

Is there a way to update this value without the user seeing a login prompt?

Edit:
This page lists several ways to accomplish the task - I've opted for the registry edit route despite being advised it's not ideal.
https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/corporatesignatures.htm

Comment: You can if needed by setting some values in the registry, but it's a bit of a pain for a few reasons. These days, the (much) better option is to set the signature on the mailbox itself - Would you rather do that? Most scripts use MSWord because it has the functionality for creating the rtf/htm/txt files used by outlook for signatures.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I actually just found a useful page that lists several ways to accomplish the task - will post link the the OG post. Are there any solid reasons that the registry edits are not advisable? I've gotten them to work.

Comment: It's just that running some quick commands on the exchange side are easier than setting up signature files and scripts to run on user machines. An additional bonus is that the settings apply to OWA and any other outlook client. If you've got something that works for you, then you're golden!

Answer (score 0):

If using Redemption (I am its author) is an option, it exposes Outlook signatures through the [RDOSignatures](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosignatures.htm) object (returned from [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Signatures`).